# Should I use DAOs from production code to setup & verify tests?

Tags: java, database, testing, tdd, clean-architecture

I'm currently working on a project that consists of multiple repositories all having a dependency to the repository which stores code for database manipulation:

- repo1 for AWS lambda1 having databaseRepo as a dependency
- repo2 for AWS lambda2 having databaseRepo as a dependency
- repo3 for AWS lambda3 having databaseRepo as a dependency
- ...
- databaseRepo - SQL scripts, Repositories & DAOs (with plain **JDBC**) for database manipulation.

We have MySQL in production and in memory H2 for testing purposes. Lets assume that I want to test logic in one of the repositories (eg. repo1) that requires some records in database in order to return success. We need to insert a row before test executes and we also assert if other row was properly modified at the end of the test. Which approach is better/cleaner for test setup and verification?

1. Using repositories/DAOs from databaseRepo (**production code**) in order to perform CRUD operations within test.
2. Creating **test** code for DAO/repository layer and use it across tests code only.

Currently we are using second approach which IMHO is better **in our case**, as we do not have databaseRepo logic well tested. However, this way we have a little bit of code duplication and we need to maintain more code.

Which approach are You using and why?

Regards,
Michal

Answer (score 1):

Cześć Michał! :) If I understood you correctly I would also go for second option. You are testing code/module that has external dependency to repository data. So you may abstract this dependency to an interface and create two implementations: one for production and one for test. In my opinion this is clean, despite it has a bit of code duplication.

Other thing you can do is to even use mocks to tell declaratively what values you expect to drive your tests.

Hope this helps. :)